# Remove an account promoting escort services

Tags: support, user-accounts, new-users, spam

I just [rejected a spam edit on MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/30896) from a new user promoting an escort service.

Looking at [the user's profile here on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/1259664/diljot-kaur), it seems to have no purpose other than (spammingly?) promoting an escort service.
Normally I'd just flag one of their posts for a moderator to handle, but there are no posts to flag so I'm resorting to posting this question.
Can one of the moderators please take a look at this?

Comment: flag one of your own posts if the account has no posts.

Comment: Thanks, I've nuked the account. And what Robert says.

Comment: I occasionally do a 'quick' search and destroy of these by certain keywords - but its on a "as I remember" basis. I've done so of a few others.  I do believe one of the chat room regulars self flags to report these users for action, or you can probably ping me on chat